# Nothing  to deleted checked item in listview in android

Tags: android, android-listview

I am trying to deleted checked item in listview in android, but I haven't achive this, why? my code is below. please response .  I have try this code as well , which has not get more idea. 
[How to delete check box items from list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9016739/how-to-delete-check-box-items-from-list)

and many more related to delete list item form list view.

```
public class BookmarksJokes extends Activity implements OnClickListener,
    OnItemClickListener {
ListView lv;
static ArrayList<Integer> checks=new ArrayList<Integer>();
static String[] tempTitle = new String[100];
static String[] tempBody = new String[100];
static String[] pos = new String[100];
private static class EfficientAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    public EfficientAdapter(Context context) {
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

    }

    public int getCount() {
        return tempTitle.length;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
         ViewHolder holder;

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.bookmarks_list_item,
                    null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();

            holder.text1 = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.titleJok);
            holder.text2 = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.bodyJok);
            holder.checkBox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkbox);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

           holder.checkBox.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {

                if(((CheckBox)v).isChecked()){
                  checks.set(position, 1);
                }
                else{
                 checks.set(position, 0);
                }

            }
        });
        holder.text1.setText(tempTitle[position]);
        holder.text2.setText(tempBody[position]);

        return convertView;
    }
     class ViewHolder {
        TextView text1;
        TextView text2;
        CheckBox checkBox;


    }
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.bokmarksjoks);

    try {
        db = (new DatabaseHelper(this)).getWritableDatabase();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    setUpViews();

    for(int b=0;b<tempTitle.length;b++){
        checks.add(b,0);              //Assign 0 by default in each position of ArrayList
            } 
    String one = pref.getString("title", "");
    String two = pref.getString("body", "");

    tempTitle = one.split(",");
    tempBody = two.split(",");

    lv.setAdapter(new EfficientAdapter(this));

    lv.setItemsCanFocus(false);
    lv.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);

    lv.setOnItemClickListener(this);
}

public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.delete:
        AlertDialog.Builder alt_bld = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        alt_bld.setMessage("Are you Sure want to delete all checked jok ?")
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton("Yes",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                    int id) {

                                for(int i=0;i<checks.size();i++){
                                    if(checks.get(i)==1){
                                        Log.d(TAG, "i  Value >>"+i);
                                            checks.remove(i);
                                            // i--;
                                            Log.d(TAG, "checked Value >>"+checks);
                                            Log.d(TAG, "i  Value -- >>"+i);
                                         }
                                     }
                                    ((EfficientAdapter)lv.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();
                                  }
                            })
                .setNegativeButton("No",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                    int id) {
                                dialog.cancel();
                            }
                        });
        AlertDialog alert = alt_bld.create();
        alert.setTitle("Delete Jokes");
        alert.show();
    case R.id.checkbox:

    default:
        break;
    }

}
```

please update this code with no errors. Or give be best idea for this.

Answer (score 0):

You are removing items from a list while traversing it. At least you must make sure to account for the removed item in the counter variable and the list size (which is why there is an i-- in the original code, but you have commented it out).

I.e. after you deleted the item with index 2, the next in the list is still 2, not 3.

Un-comment the i--, that should fix it.

Comment: Ok i have try to uncomment this i--, but still first i have checked and click deleted button, could not delete any items from list

Answer (score 0):

you want to delete checked item, but not modifying data source of list, please load data source from checks list. as Below:

```
public class BookmarksJokes extends Activity implements OnClickListener,
    OnItemClickListener {
ListView lv;
static ArrayList<Integer> checks=new ArrayList<Integer>();
static ArrayList<String> tempTitle = new String[100];
static ArrayList<String> tempBody = new String[100];
static String[] pos = new String[100];
private static class EfficientAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    public EfficientAdapter(Context context) {
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

    }

    public int getCount() {
        return tempTitle.length;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
         ViewHolder holder;

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.bookmarks_list_item,
                    null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();

            holder.text1 = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.titleJok);
            holder.text2 = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.bodyJok);
            holder.checkBox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkbox);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

           holder.checkBox.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {

                if(((CheckBox)v).isChecked()){
                  checks.set(position, 1);
                }
                else{
                 checks.set(position, 0);
                }

            }
        });
        holder.text1.setText(tempTitle.get(position));
        holder.text2.setText(tempBody.get(position));

        return convertView;
    }
     class ViewHolder {
        TextView text1;
        TextView text2;
        CheckBox checkBox;


    }
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.bokmarksjoks);

    try {
        db = (new DatabaseHelper(this)).getWritableDatabase();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    setUpViews();

    for(int b=0;b<tempTitle.size();b++){
        checks.add(b,0);              //Assign 0 by default in each position of ArrayList
            } 
    String one = pref.getString("title", "");
    String two = pref.getString("body", "");

    String[] tokens = one.split(",");
    tempTitle=Arrays.asList(tokens);
    tokens= two.split(",");
    tempBody =Arrays.asList(tokens);

    lv.setAdapter(new EfficientAdapter(this));

    lv.setItemsCanFocus(false);
    lv.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);

    lv.setOnItemClickListener(this);
}

public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.delete:
        AlertDialog.Builder alt_bld = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        alt_bld.setMessage("Are you Sure want to delete all checked jok ?")
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton("Yes",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                    int id) {

                                for(int i=0;i<checks.size();i++){
                                    if(checks.get(i)==1){
                                        Log.d(TAG, "i  Value >>"+i);
                                            checks.remove(i);
                                            tempTitle.remove(i);
                                            tempBody.remove(i);
                                            // i--;
                                            Log.d(TAG, "checked Value >>"+checks);
                                            Log.d(TAG, "i  Value -- >>"+i);
                                         }
                                     }
                                    ((EfficientAdapter)lv.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();
                                  }
                            })
                .setNegativeButton("No",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                    int id) {
                                dialog.cancel();
                            }
                        });
        AlertDialog alert = alt_bld.create();
        alert.setTitle("Delete Jokes");
        alert.show();
    case R.id.checkbox:

    default:
        break;
    }

}
```

Comment: I have faced.. on """checks.lenght and holder.text1.setText(checks[position]);
        holder.text2.setText(checks[position]);"""error this>> .The type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to ArrayList<Integer>

Comment: Here, temp.remove(position); in this line you have passed position, where you declare this.Is this id? i try id but noting work fine.

Comment: Actually, Its not id, its i, I am not compiling code, so it may have still error.

Comment: According to you code,Some change but not work>>> List<String> temp=Arrays.asList(tempTitle);
temp.remove(pos);
tempTitle=(String[]) temp.toArray();
                                         temp=Arrays.asList(tempBody);
temp.remove(pos);
tempBody=(String[]) temp.toArray(); Pos is already declared above see that.